# How do I push to private repo using an account credentials not associated with my pubkey?

Tags: git, github

I have two Github accounts (I know this is kind of dumb, but it's company policy):

`UserA` is my **work** account, and I authenticate using my pubkey on my **work machine**.

`UserB` is my **personal** account, and want to push to a private repo from my **work machine**, using my **personal** username/password as credentials (as opposed to a pubkey).

However, when I try to `push` to a private repo on a `UserB` account from my work machine, I get a permissions error:

```
ERROR: Permission to <UserB>/<new repo>.git denied to <UserA>.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The new repo definitely exists on Github.

As [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551409/how-to-change-git-ssh-user-for-a-remote-push-temporarily) have suggested, I have tried `git push <UserB>@github.com:<UserB>/<new repo>.git master:master`, but I get a similar error: `Permission denied (publickey).`

How do I force git to authenticate as `UserB` on `push` without adding the SSh key from my work machine to the `UserB` account??

Comment: Use HTTPS url: `git push https://github.com/<UserB>/<new repo>.git master:master`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I manage multiple ssh keys to be used on two different private repository in GIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36210593/how-do-i-manage-multiple-ssh-keys-to-be-used-on-two-different-private-repository)

Comment: @phd I am not asking how to manage two different keys, I am asking how to auth with username/password on different account.

Comment: And the second SSH key is the answer. Or switch to http(s). Or temporary disable (comment it out in the config) the first SSH key.

Answer (score 0):

Create another key on your local machine and associate it to the other account.